# How should I go about replacing src="/media/static/admin/js/core.js" with src="{% static "admin/js/core.js" %}"?

Tags: regex, django, sed

I have to replace thousands of occurrences like this in a bunch of django templates.

The hard coded version:

```
 src="/media/static/admin/js/core.js"
```

What I need:

```
src="{% static "admin/js/core.js" %}"
```

Where `admin/js/core.js` is variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command got me much closer:

```
find . -iname *.html |  xargs sed -i 's!"/media/static/\(.*\)"!"{% static "\1" %}"!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: (basically, put `\` befor any `/` or `.` or other characters that are specific to regexp or sed)

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/\/media\/static\/admin\/js\/core\.js/\{\% static \"admin\/js\/core\.js\" \%\}/g' {} +
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it's not always going to be admin/js/core.js. I will have some that are src="{% static "admin/js/jquery.js" %}" and many others as well.

Comment: Well, then run a similar command as above for each different url :)

Comment: I wish I could. I don't know how many different urls there are. I need a regex that can handle that variable portion of the path automatically.

Comment: Look at all relevant template files. You will find out what urls need to be replaced. Then write a 'find sed' similar to above for each of them. There is no one-size-fit-all solution for your problem.